# Css height:0 undocumented property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

i have main grid with 2 columns. grid take 1 fr height.
In right column i want create scrolled div with take all height.

**We all know that flex dont overflow need apply min-height/min-width: 0;**

But i 2 hour try apply all combination for stop height overflow. And what did i find ?
min-height dont give nothing in my example. But i miss click and write rule height:0 and overflow stopped! what is magic ? I didnt find nothing in google about it undocumented property!

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-teal-200 flex flex-col">
  <div class="h-20 bg-indigo-400">header</div>

    <div class="flex-grow grid grid-cols-[300px_1fr] grid-rows-1 bg-green-200">
      <div>left short content</div>
      <div class="flex flex-col">
        <div class="flex-grow bg-rose-300 overflow-y-scroll min-h-0 h-0">
              <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
              <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
              <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
              <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
              <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
              <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="h-20 bg-indigo-400">footer</div>
</div>
```

[image]

sandbox:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/3fyrMQK6Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making the element `h-0` it will have a height equal to 0 thus it won't contribute to the dimension of the grid (it's like it doesn't exist). Later it will grow to fill the space with the `flex-grow`

---

If you want to work with `min-height` you have to do is to consider `h-screen` instead of `min-h-screen` then `min-h-0` on the second child element. You have to also disable the shrinking on header and footer:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen bg-teal-200 flex flex-col">
  <div class="h-20 flex-shrink-0 bg-indigo-400">header</div>
  <div class="flex-grow grid grid-cols-[300px_1fr] grid-rows-1 bg-green-200 min-h-0">
    <div>left short content</div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="flex-grow bg-rose-300 overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
        <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
        <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
        <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
        <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
        <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-20 flex-shrink-0 bg-indigo-400">footer</div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify like below:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen bg-teal-200 grid grid-cols-[300px_1fr] grid-rows-[auto_1fr_auto]">
  <div class="h-20 bg-indigo-400 col-span-2">header</div>
  <div class="bg-green-200">left short content</div>
  <div class="bg-rose-300 overflow-y-scroll">
    <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
    <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
    <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
    <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
    <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
    <div class="h-60 border border-black"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="h-20 bg-indigo-400 col-span-2">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that I need variability, that is, not to change the styles of the entire template (cant apply h-screen), but only the central right part. There may be other content in this part that will exceed the page size and expand accordingly. And there will be content like now with blocks that should not overflow.

Comment: But of course the most important question is what is this magical property height:0 which does what I need :D . And why does min-height not work in my example?

Comment: @padavan height:0 is accidentally doing what you need. There is no magic but you are making an element with 0 height so it won't affect the dimension (it's like it's not there) and will trigger an overflow .. you **have** to set set h-screen or any height if you want to have scrolling otherwise the elements will expand to fit the content

Comment: this element take full size you can see on chrome dev tools.  height: 0; != height:0px;

Comment: @padavan because you are also using flex-grow that will make the element grow

Comment: why we should set h-screen ? does it work differently for height than for width? example for width i dont apply 'w-screen' https://play.tailwindcss.com/QXIQzXQ3nM

Comment: @padavan you don't w-screen because the element are by default width:100% of their container. With height it's different, the height is defined by content unlike the width